# Unchanged `lambda.min` values for multiple LASSO regressions in R

Tags: r, lambda, regression, lasso-regression

I'm trying to perform multiple LASSO regressions in R using the following code:

```
library(readxl)
data <-read_excel("data.xlsx") # 20x20 matrix  
library(glmnet)
    library(coefplot)
    
    A <- as.matrix(data)
    results <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(A)), function(i) {
      list(
    fit_lasso = glmnet(A[, -i], A[, i], standardize = T, alpha = 1), 
    cvfit = cv.glmnet(A[, -i] , A[, i] , standardize = TRUE , type.measure = "mse" , nfolds = 10 , alpha = 1)
  )
})
coefficients <- lapply(results, function(x, fun) fun(coef(x$cvfit, s = "lambda.min")), function(x) x[x[, 1L] != 0L, 1L, drop = FALSE])
```

My output `results` results in a `Large list (20 elements, 1MB)` with 20 same LASSO output but for 20 variables and `coefficients` output is only the significant variables in each case.

I notice that for the same dataset the results are not always the same - maybe because of lambda changing values in each run? not sure. I want to make my code to find the  same `lambda.min`'s and give always the same results when I run the dataset. I believe a set.seed() might manage it but can't figure out how to sufficiently include it.

How can I always make it print the same outputs for a specific dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to produce the same `lambda.min` values from run to run just by putting `set.seed()` before the list.  Then, you're setting the seed for the random draws of the cross-validation runs.

```
library(readxl)
data <-read_excel("data.xlsx") # 20x20 matrix  
library(glmnet)
    library(coefplot)
    
    A <- as.matrix(data)
 set.seed(54234)   
 results <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(A)), function(i) {
      list(
    fit_lasso = glmnet(A[, -i], A[, i], standardize = T, alpha = 1), 
    cvfit = cv.glmnet(A[, -i] , A[, i] , standardize = TRUE , type.measure = "mse" , nfolds = 10 , alpha = 1)
  )
})
coefficients <- lapply(results, function(x, fun) fun(coef(x$cvfit, s = "lambda.min")), function(x) x[x[, 1L] != 0L, 1L, drop = FALSE])
```

Comment: does the number of set.seed  can affect the effectiveness of the results? I mean is there an  optimal seed?

Comment: A different value of set.seed will produce a different result, but that result will be the same if you run the function again. The results are inherently variable because of the randomness in the cross validation.